# Scipy KSTest TypeError: _parse_args() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given

Tags: python, scipy

I'm trying to get the best fitting distribution for the set of values I have. I came up with the following function to do that.

```
def get_best_distribution(data):
    dist_names = [st.exponweib, st.weibull_max, st.weibull_min,st.pareto, st.genextreme]
    dist_results = []
    params = {}
    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = dist_name
        param = dist.fit(data)

        params[dist_name] = param
        # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
        D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
        dist_results.append((dist_name, p))

    # select the best fitted distribution
    best_dist, best_p = (max(dist_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))
    # store the name of the best fit and its p value

    print("Best fitting distribution: "+st(best_dist))
    print("Best p value: "+ str(p))
    print("Parameters for the best fit: "+ str(params[best_dist]))

    return best_dist, best_p, params[best_dist]
```

As per the Scipy documentation, everything should be fine. But this gives the following error.

```
TypeError: _parse_args() takes from 3 to 5 positional arguments but 6 were given
```

What causes this?

Following line causes this error.

```
D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
```

Thank you

Comment: You could do a little debugging.  Cut `dist_names` down to just *one* distribution (pick one).  Does the error still occur?

Comment: Yes. It does. This is the line that causes the error. D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue solved using following modifications.

```
def get_best_distribution(data):
    dist_names = ["exponweib", "weibull_max", "weibull_min", "pareto", "genextreme"]
    dist_results = []
    params = {}
    for dist_name in dist_names:
        dist = getattr(st, dist_name)
        param = dist.fit(data)

        params[dist_name] = param
        # Applying the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test
        D, p = st.kstest(data, dist_name, args=param)
        print("p value for "+dist_name+" = "+str(p))
        dist_results.append((dist_name, p))

    # select the best fitted distribution
    best_dist, best_p = (max(dist_results, key=lambda item: item[1]))
    # store the name of the best fit and its p value

    print("Best fitting distribution: "+str(best_dist))
    print("Best p value: "+ str(p))
    print("Parameters for the best fit: "+ str(params[best_dist]))

    return best_dist, best_p, params[best_dist]
```